# Pandas dataframe amend entry based on partial match with previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big Dataframe like this, where Item is a column of strings:

```
Ref    Item
4      blue 14A square
16     blue 14A rectangle
19     red 15 oval
21     red 22C square
33     blue 101 square
38     blue 14A square
41     blue 6F square
42     blue 6F triangle
47     blue 6F circle
51     blue 95 oval
58     red 15 square
64     red 15 oval
71     blue 14A square
```

I want to insert `(copy)` after the colour and value if they are the same as the previous row, preserving the order.

Desired output:

```
Ref    Item
4      blue 14A square
16     blue 14A (copy) rectangle
19     red 15 oval
21     red 22C square
33     blue 101 square
38     blue 14A square
41     blue 6F square
42     blue 6F (copy) triangle
47     blue 6F (copy) circle
51     blue 95 oval
58     red 15 square
64     red 15 (copy) oval
71     blue 14A square
```

A second best solution would be for `(copy)` to go at the end of the Item entry, eg `red 15 oval (copy)` in ref 64.

I have had a play around with `groupby`, but I don't want to group as such - I'm only interested in matching with the previous row. I've also tried `np.where` with `shift`, but I'm struggling to create something that matches only the colour and value parts of Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try via `rsplit()` ,`assign()` and `shift()` method:

```
df=df.assign(color=df['Item'].str.rsplit(' ',1).str[0],item=df['Item'].str.rsplit(' ',1).str[1])
#assigned 2 columns named color and item by splitting Item column 

shifted=df['color'].shift(1)

mask=df['color']==shifted
#created boolean mask

df[mask]=df[mask].assign(Item=df['color']+' (copy) '+df['item'])
#passed boolean mask
```

Finally use `drop()` method:

```
df=df.drop(['color','item'],1)
#removed previously assigned columns
```

Now IF you print `df` you will get your desired output

Comment: Superb. Thank you!